# Autosuggestbox not displaying results WP8.1 Universal App

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, mvvm-light, autosuggest

Results template in autosuggestbox are not showing and I don't know why. I'm using MVVM Light in the app. Let's go with the code :)

In the page:

```
<AutoSuggestBox x:Name="txtBusqueda" x:Uid="txtBusqueda" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Lugares}"
        Grid.Row="1" Margin="24 24 24 12" 
        MaxSuggestionListHeight="4" AutoMaximizeSuggestionArea="True" 
        TextMemberPath="Nombre"
    >
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="TextChanged">
                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ChangeTextCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtBusqueda}" />
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nombre}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
    </AutoSuggestBox>
```

In the VM:

```
private List<LugarInfo> lugares;
public List<LugarInfo> Lugares
{
    get { return this.lugares; }
    set
    {
        if (this.lugares == value) return;
        this.lugares = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Lugares);
    }
}
public RelayCommand<string> ChangeTextCommand { get; set; }
this.ChangeTextCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(async (s) =>
{
    var result = await Api.GetInfoLugares(texto);
    List<LugarInfo> lugares = new List<LugarInfo>();
    foreach (var lugar in result)
    {
            lugares.Add(new LugarInfo()
            {
                Id = int.Parse(lugar.Id),
                Tipo = lugar.Tipo,
                Nombre = lugar.Nombre
            });
    }

    this.Lugares = lugares;
});
```

So, as you can see, not too much trouble. 
The results are returned and assigned to the property:
[image: Results in code]

The problem is results are not displayed in control as you can see in the image.
[image: Autosuggest image]
Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you add that red outline?  That is usually an indication that there is a binding problem.

Comment: @Paul Abbott That bottom red line appears when I set the property in the VM...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your Lugares property will never raise RaisePropertyChanged because in your code you are adding your objects in lugares and than assigning it to This.Lugares which in setter is same so it will not raise the property change and and UI is not updated. change your code to as follows.

```
var myLugares = new List<LugarInfo>();
foreach (var lugar in result)
{
        myLugares.Add(new LugarInfo()
        {
            Id = int.Parse(lugar.Id),
            Tipo = lugar.Tipo,
            Nombre = lugar.Nombre
        });
}

this.Lugares = myLugares;
```

Comment: I will try this in a few hours when I return home and give you feedback, thanks.

Comment: I've changed and tested the code some minutes ago and unfortunately the results does not appear in the control :( The property change is raising now but as I've said...no luck

Comment: After 2 days, I realise about this: MaxSuggestionListHeight="4".... what a shame... sorry guys and thanks for the help. It's working now...